# ASP.Net error on server?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, server

I have an ASP.Net site that pulls back data from a SQL database, it works in visual studio on my local machine but when i upload it to my web space at [somee.com](http://somee.com/) i get an error when i try to access the page.

Here i the error page :

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Configuration Error

Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file           required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below   and modify your configuration file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data, Version=6.9.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Source Error: 


An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

Source File: d:\DZHosts\LocalUser\bman262\www.brandonsLoginTest.somee.com\riviera horticulture\web.config    Line: 9 

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'MySql.Data, Version=6.9.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' could not be loaded.


WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value     [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET      Version:4.6.1069.1
```

From what i can make of that, i don't think the

```
mysql.data
```

reference in the web config is getting loaded in.

Anyone help ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You either need to make sure that the missing DLL is included when you deploy your web site. If you use the VS deploy tool, it should do this for you.

Check your Publish folder and see if it's there.

Comment: Thanks for the help, What DLL could be missing or what DLL should i try adding ? and were would it be in my publish folder if it was there, i cant seem to see anything other then my site pages and resources ?

Comment: Don't know the exact name of the DLL, but as MySqlData is the missing dataspace, I would hazard a guess that it's the main MySql DLL that's missing. If you don't see anything other than your own files in the publish folder, then it sounds like your publish isn't working right. You should have some Microsoft stuff in there as well

Comment: Hi there ive done some looking around about what you said and figured out that i was useing the dll on my dev machine not the dll local to my file, i downloaded the sql dlls and added them localy in my project folder as references. this solved one un mentioned problem i was having with my project not working on other machine's. It also changed the error im getting on the server. now i have added the dll into my file and used that referance the server says theres an error with my code rather then the web.config it says it cant find mysql.data when i use Using mysql.data

Comment: @Bman262 you certainly need to add references to any DLLs you want to use. That way, the publish wizard knows what to include when creating the package. You don't actually need to copy them into your project though, as I said, the publish wizard will add them in for you.

Comment: Ok in that case it seems the publish wizard is not doing that for some reason. Am i maybe publishing my project wrong ? i right click on my solution and press publish then i publish to a file ?

Comment: @Bman262 that's how I publish, and it always copies all the referenced DLLs into the publish folder. Not sure why it's not working for you. Maybe try a new MVC project, set the mode to release and publish it. See if that includes all the files. If it does, then it sounds like there's something wrong with your project. If not, it sounds like there's something wrong with your VS install